# gulp.watch не видит новые файлы

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, sass

```
gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'js', 'pug', 'browser-sync'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['app/blocks/**/*.sass', 'app/sass/**/*.sass'], ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(['app/*.pug', 'app/blocks/**/*.pug', 'app/settings/settings.pug'], ['pug']);
  gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], ['js']);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload)});
```

Есть вот такой таск. Но когда создаю новые файлы в блоке ===>[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот блоки

gulp.watch'ер отказывается их видеть в запущенном режиме gulp default

Answer (score 0):

Возможно надо либо таску watch переименовать в default либо запускать gulp watch. Ниже рабочий пример. Запускаю gulp default и watch внутри default срабатывает, всё пересобирается при изменении файлов.

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
    var concat = require('gulp-concat');

    gulp.task('js', function(){
        gulp.src('./js/*.js')
            .pipe(concat('main.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    });

    gulp.task('default', ['js'], function(){
        gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['js']);
    });
```